# Laravel 5.5: Can't sent email via google (SSL operation failed)

Tags: php, laravel

I saw the  bellow settings for `.env` in answers on similar questions:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=somePassword1234
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

However, nothing works. With, `tls` encryption, I got error

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:
ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

With `ssl` encryption, I got error:

```
Swift_TransportException
Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ***Editor's note***: disabling SSL verification has **security implications.** Without verification of the authenticity of SSL/HTTPS connections, a malicious attacker can impersonate a trusted endpoint such as Gmail, and you'll be vulnerable to a [Man-in-the-Middle Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
>
> ## **Be sure you fully understand the security issues before using this as a solution.**

You must disable signing the letter with a certificate in config mail file: `mail.php`

```
return [ 
....
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
],
....
];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It was an attempt to send email, but I got `Swift_TransportException (535)
Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.` this time. I tried to login with same password in gmail manually from browser - no problem, email and password are correct.

Comment: I got email from google. It thinks that someone use my password and blocks this activity. It's very good security system, by how I should to test the email sending...

Comment: @GurebuBokofu enable two factor authentication on Gmail and then create an app password to use specifically for this purpose.